# Python - a bytes like object is required, not str

Tags: python, python-3.x, irc, twitch

I'm moving my Twitch bot from Python 2.7 to Python 3.5. I keep getting the error: 
`a bytes like object is required not 'str'` on the 2nd line of the code below.

```
twitchdata = irc.recv(1204)
    data = twitchdata.split(":")[1]
    twitchuser = data.split("!")[0]
    twitchmsg = twitchdata.split(":")[2]
    chat = str(twitchuser) +": "+ str(twitchmsg)
    print(chat) #prints chat to console
```

Comment: See also: Ned Batcheler's [Pragmatic Unicode, or, How Do I Stop the Pain?](http://bit.ly/unipain)

Answer (score 99):

try

```
data = twitchdata.decode().split(":")[1]
```

instead of

```
data = twitchdata.split(":")[1]
```

Comment: I think you mean `decode`. And of course the same would be needed for the other `split` calls, so the decoding should happen once, in the first line. Plus the question if ASCII is even the right encoding...

Comment: I think is only decode() and I think is related to https://docs.python.org/release/3.0.1/whatsnew/3.0.html#text-vs-data-instead-of-unicode-vs-8-bit

Comment: Thank you. I used data = twitchdata.decode("ascii").split(":")[1] and that worked

Comment: I thing is better without ascii, it  will free your code from issues with unicode

Comment: I ve solved the same issue with  
`bytes(my_str, encoding='UTF-8')`  

and removing everything that was left for PY2 compatibility.