# How can this simple Python 2 code be translated to Python 3? [Python Student]

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

The answer on this post, https://stackoverflow.com/a/16175368/6448312 is failing to run for me on Python 3. I'm getting the error of -

```
#$>test2.py Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:\Users\.\OneDrive\PROJECTS for fun\smartApp\test2.py", line 4, in <module>
for row in output.split('\n'): TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

I am using the same code they posted - https://hastebin.com/ubafadikos.py

It seems like I need to cast the string to a byte type, I've tried using, `newOutput = bytes(output, 'utf-8')` but that is failing too with the error message of

```
newOutput = bytes(output, 'utf-8')
TypeError: str() takes at most 1 argument (2 given)
```

I'm at a loss for what to try next :( I'm using Python 3.6.1, running the code on Python 2.7 works fine.

**EDIT:** Using newOutput = bytes(output) works

Comment: Your first error message looks like a Python 3 error message, but your second error message looks like a Python 2 error message. Something's really weird about how you're running this code.

Comment: @user2357112 Thanks for the comment, both outputs are from Python3. I took out the second argument as it said it didn't want more than 1 for newOutput = bytes(output, 'utf-8') and the code ran successfully. 

However I'm not sure if that's syntactically correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `for row in output.decode().split('\n')`

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29643544/python-a-bytes-like-object-is-required-not-str)

Comment: Awesome, thanks. I really wish they could add some hints to Python error messages to point out things like this.