# My program keeps saying " a bytes-like object is required, not 'str' " on if "<!--__BEGIN_TOR_NODE_LIST__-->" not in page.content:

Tags: python, html

What I am trying to do is make a program that goes to the website https://www.dan.me.uk/tornodes, takes what tor node IP addresses are on that website and checks to see if there is a match on my list of IP addresses.

Using Python

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

page = requests.get('https://www.dan.me.uk/tornodes')

if "<!--__BEGIN_TOR_NODE_LIST__-->" not in page.content:
    print("LIST IS NOT READY")
else:
    list_text = page.content.split("<!--__BEGIN_TOR_NODE_LIST__-->")[1] #TAKES EVERYTHING AFTER THIS
    list_text = list_text.split("<!--__END_TOR_NODE_LIST__-->")[1] #TAKES EVERYTHING BEFORE THIS
    line_list = [line.strip() ]
    for line in list_text.split("<br>"):
        line_ip = line.strip().split("|")[0]
        #DO WHAT YOU WANT NOW
        if line_ip in my_known_ip_list:
            print("THIS IS GOOD" % line_ip)
```

Greatly appreciate any help given to me in advance.

Comment: as the error implies , content probably required byte type. You can try to print out page and page.content to check

Comment: `page.content` will always return a `bytes` type. If you want a string, you'll need `page.content.decode().split()`

Comment: @C.Nivs Thank you that worked!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python - a bytes like object is required, not str](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29643544/python-a-bytes-like-object-is-required-not-str)